# Find closest point using L.GeometryUtil.closest and open its popup

Tags: leaflet, geojson, point, popup, close

How do I use:

`L.GeometryUtil.closest(myMap, coords, b)`

to find the closest point in a geojson point layer in leaflet. I have tried several things. And the error I receive is: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
    let coords=[]; 

    let closetPt;

    lyrPts = L.geoJSON.ajax('Geojson/pts.geojson',{
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerPts);
      },
        onEachFeature: function (feature) {
                 coords.push(feature.geometry.coordinates);
        }
    }).bindTooltip(function(layer){
      return layer.feature.properties.Layer
    }).addTo(myMap);

    closestPt = L.GeometryUtil.closestLayer(myMap, coords, [-40.5512, 80.9454]);
```

---

This part now works when I take out closestPt and put it in a callback.

Is it possible to now automatically open the popup of this closest marker?

I want to use it so that as you are within a distance X of a point, its popup will be displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). `coords` is an empty array when `L.GeometryUtil.closest()` runs.

Be sure to wait until the remote GeoJSON file is loaded first.

Answer (score 2):

Since [`L.GeometryUtil.closest`](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#closest) works on either of `Array.<L.LatLng> | Array.<Array.<L.LatLng>> | L.PolyLine | L.Polygon` you will have to pass an array of the coordinates of the GeoJSON point layer to it.

The following code gets an array of points from the point layer ([`getLayers()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#geojson-getlayers)) and stores their coordinates in `coordinates_array`, which can be used in `L.GeometryUtil.closest`:

```
const coordinates_array = bicycle_layer.getLayers().map(l => l.feature.geometry.coordinates)
let closest_latlng = L.GeometryUtil.closest(map, coordinates_array, [-40.5512, 80.9454])
```

`closest_latlng` then contains: `Object { lat: -85.05112877979998, lng: 39.75028330000001, distance: 825385.8575732928 }`

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/newluck77/p17x28Lz/

Comment: getLayers() returns an empty array for my geojson layer

Comment: Appears to be something wrong with my array. Is there a way to check its validity?

Comment: I think this is because of a race condition (ajax is asynchronous after all) and `getLayers` is called before the data is loaded. You can try something like `lyrPts.on('add', e => e.target.getLayers()) //fires when layer is added to the map`

Comment: Any ideas on how I would have the closest point automatically open as a popup when I am within a distance of X meters of it? Thanks

Comment: I think that's for a new question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask